# jquery ajax loaded data option selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Here is my html that will loaded with ajax call.

```
           <select id="choice-id" name="choice_name">
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3" selected="">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="6">6</option>
            </select>
           <div style="display: block;" id="select" class="other">
              <input id="other-0" name="other_0" type="text" value="abc">
              <input id="other-1" name="other_1" type="text" value="pqr">
              <input id="other-2" name="other_2" type="text" value="rst">
           </div>
```

here is my jquery for changing input field corresponding to option select. if i select option with value '6' it will generate 6 input field without any values.

```
$(document).on('change','#choice-id',function() {
        var choicesizeSelected = $("#choice-id :selected").val();   
        $('.other').empty();
        for(var i=0; i<choicesizeSelected; i++) {
        $('.other').append("<input id='other-"+i+"' type='text' name='other_"+i+"'></input>");
            }
}
```

this code is working perfectly. but if i select again default option 3, i want return default 3 input field with same values.

thanks in advance.

Comment: could you create a jsfiddle, http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is emptying the whole `.other` div.

Instead, compare if the number of inputs is bigger or smaller than selected.

If the selected number is bigger: **add fields**
If the selected number is smaller: **remove fields**
If the selected number is the same: **do nothing**

```
$(function() {
    $('#choice-id').on('change', function() {
        var newNum = $(this).find(':selected').val();
        var oldNum = $('.other input').length;

        if( oldNum > newNum ) {
            var x = parseInt(newNum)+1;
            $('.other input:nth-child(n+'+x+')').remove();
        }
        else if( oldNum < newNum ) {
            for( var i=oldNum; i<newNum; i++ ) {
                $('.other').append("<input id='other-"+i+"' type='text' name='other_"+i+"'></input>");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/qe5kcnLe/)